# How to cast, in C++, a byte vector (std::vector<uint8_t>) into different uint32_t, uint16_t and uint8_t variables

Tags: c++, vector, byte

I have vector of bytes, std::vector, and I want to extract its information to some integers of different length.

For example I could have a vector of 7 bytes and I would like to read a uint32_t at the beginning, then a uint16_t and last a uint8_t. I need a way to specify at which element of the vector should it start reading and how many bytes should be read.

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t>& bytes(7);
uint32_t a;
uint16_t b;
uint8_t c;

// Could be something similar to this? 
// This yields an invalid conversion error: {aka unsigned char}’ to ‘const void*’
std::memcpy(&a, bytes[0], sizeof(uint32_t)); 
std::memcpy(&a, bytes[4], sizeof(uint16_t));
std::memcpy(&a, bytes[6], sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Comment: You should be careful about undefined behaviour and the like. That said, I recall there is a method for getting the underlying array for a `std::vector`, which might be useful, you might be able to find it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector .

Comment: Note that in this approach, the bytes of the integers must be in the CPU native byte order in the array. This would result in different values on CPU's with different endianness, given the same array. This would be a problem if the data is used for serialisation across systems (for example, over a network).

Comment: Are you aware that this kind of conversion depends on (proper) [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: Yes, I'm taking endianness into account. Actually, the bytes are transmitted over the network between two devices with the same endianness.

Comment: The three memcpy are all copying bytes into `a`.  The other two probably should be `b` and `c`.

Comment: @Eljay, yes, thank you for the heads up, it was just an error for the minimal example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the address of the element in the vector to achieve what you want:

```
std::memcpy(&a, &bytes[0], sizeof(std::uint32_t));
//              ^
//or use .data() instead
std::memcpy(&a, bytes.data() + 0, sizeof(std::uint32_t));
```

Comment: Why do you need `+ 0`?

Comment: @Evg To demonstrate how to get pointer to element at an index. In the example, the element is at index 0.